# How to resolve problem with es_extended Fivem (Lua)

Tags: lua, grand-theft-auto, fivem

i have a problem with es_extended.

I have this error : 
`SCRIPT ERROR: @es_extended/client/main.lua:64: attempt to index a nil value (field 'coords')`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code at line 64?

Comment: Line 63 - 79 :
ESX.Game.Teleport(PlayerPedId(), {
  x = playerData.coords.x,
  y = playerData.coords.y,
  z = playerData.coords.z + 0.25,
  heading = playerData.coords.heading
 }, function()
  TriggerServerEvent('esx:onPlayerSpawn')
  TriggerEvent('esx:onPlayerSpawn')
  TriggerEvent('playerSpawned') -- compatibility with old scripts, will be   removed soon
  TriggerEvent('esx:restoreLoadout')

  Citizen.Wait(3000)
  ShutdownLoadingScreen()
  FreezeEntityPosition(PlayerPedId(), false)
  DoScreenFadeIn(10000)
  StartServerSyncLoops()
 end)

Comment: And the link of the es_extended that I downloaded : https://github.com/ESX-Brasil/es_extended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be fixed by checking if the coordinates have a value before attempting to teleport the player.

```
    if playerData.coords == nil and playerData.coords.x == nil then playerData.coords = {x = -1070.906250, y = -2972.122803, z = 13.773568} end

    ESX.Game.Teleport(PlayerPedId(), {
       x = playerData.coords.x,
       y = playerData.coords.y,
       z = playerData.coords.z + 0.25
    }, function()
       TriggerServerEvent('esx:onPlayerSpawn')
       TriggerEvent('esx:onPlayerSpawn')
       TriggerEvent('playerSpawned') -- compatibility with old scripts, will be removed soon
       TriggerEvent('esx:restoreLoadout')

       Citizen.Wait(3000)
       ShutdownLoadingScreen()
       FreezeEntityPosition(PlayerPedId(), false)
       DoScreenFadeIn(10000)
       StartServerSyncLoops()
   end)
```